# Can I trigger the fr-visit-all event from a button or using JavaScript?

Tags: orbeon

[The documentation](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/error-summary.html#marking-all-controls-as-visited) describes how to trigger the `fr-visit-all` event. Is it possible to define a process and/or a button that triggers this event. Or trigger it using JavaScript? In some cases I would like all of the errors to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From a process, you can use the [`visit-all` action](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html).
- From JavaScript, I would use `ORBEON.xforms.Document.dispatchEvent()` to [dispatch an event to XForms](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/client-side-javascript-api.html#dispatching-events), and in XForms upon receiving that event, you can call a process with `process:runProcessByName()` as done in [process-button.xbl](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/process-button/process-button.xbl).

Comment: Thanks. Configuring a button to execute `visit-all` works well. I tried using `ORBEON.xforms.Document.dispatchEvent({targetId: 'fr-form-instance', eventName: 'fr-visit-all'})`. I thought this would be equivalent, but the function just returns `undefined` and nothing happens. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: This is correct: you can't just dispatch `fr-visit-all` to `fr-form-instance`, or anything else for that matter. If you've seen anything in the doc that made you believe that would work, just let me know so we can clarify it.